# Does norm of discrepancy decrease monotonously in CGLS/CGNR

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I am the author of the package for tomographic reconstruction https://github.com/kulvait/KCT_cbct I have implemented CGLS/CGNR , algorithm which applies conjugate gradients on normal equation

$$
A^\top A x = A^\top b
$$
I use CGLS/CGNR as a default algorithm for many tomographic problems. Let's say $x_i$ is the solution after $i$-th iteration. I compute sequence of solutions. I report the norm of discrepancy
$$
d_i = \|Ax_i-b\|
$$
and the norm of residual
$$
r_i = \|A^\top A x_i -A^\top b\|
$$
to see the speed of convergence based on sequences $(r_i)$ and (d_i).

I note that the norm of residual $(r_i)$ is not always decreasing monotonously but sometimes it jumps up. As conjugate gradients guarantee to minimize norm of error, this is expected behavior. What is interesting I have never seen for any problem the sequence of norm of discrepancy $(d_i)$, which is non monotonous. Now the question is is that just coincidence?

So I would like to prove or to show an counterexample for the following **claim**.

For all positive definite $A^\top A$ the CGLS behaves such that
$$
\|Ax_{i+1}-b\| \leq \|Ax_{i}-b\|
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_i)$ be sequence of solutions to CGLS/CGNR and let $x^*$ be a solution of
$$A^\top A x^* = A^\top b$$

AS CG minimizes $A$ norm of error over growing Krylov subspace, CGLS/CGNR minimizes $A^\top A$ norm of error which is

$$\|x^* - x_i\|_{A^\top A} = \|A x^* - A x_i\|$$
thus we have
$$\|A x^* - A x_{i+1}\| \leq \|A x^* - A x_i\|$$

Now from the properties of the least squares solution we can decompose
$$b = A x^* + b^\perp, \mbox{where} $$
$b^\perp$ is orthogonal to the column space of $A$ and thus
$$\|b - A x_{i}\| = \|b^\perp\| + \|A x^* - A x_{i}\|.$$
Therefore we conclude that the statement
$$\|A x_{i+1} - b\| \leq \| A x_{i} - b \|$$
is true.

Thanks to Zdeněk Strakoš for outlining this answer.